# How to expand weekly time series data from 38 weeks to 52 weeks format?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, interpolation

Recently I have been working with weekly data that has in total 52 weeks. Later I received data with an external variable and it is also in weekly format but the whole year has in total 38 weeks. The difference comes from wider ranges for a given week in the second dataset. If there's any possibility to expand the 38 week data to 52 week one?

@ EDIT: Solution

I used GAMs with splines and it gave me desired output. The code:

```
time <- seq_along(data)
model <- gam(data ~ s(time, k=38), family=poisson(), method="REML")

new_time <- seq(1, 38, length.out = 52)
prediction <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(time=new_time))
```

Comment: "wider ranges for a given week"; are you talking about weeks that are 365 / 38 ~= 9.6 days long? That fits your solution as well but is a very liberal interpretation of what a "week" is. Are you sure you're not just missing some weeks?

Comment: As I checked my solution doesn't work - it gives strangely low numbers. I'm sure I'm not missing anything. It's just the strange format that data is stored. The data comes from here: http://wwwold.pzh.gov.pl/oldpage/epimeld/grypa/2019/2019.htm . There are only 48 weeks as sometimes the report takes wider range, for example: Decembers range is  23.12-31.12. I clearly have no idea how to resolve this problem.

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own question by writing it in the Answer box. Doing so allows you to gain points both for the Question and the Answer. But also note that a high-quality answer will include some amount of explanation of what the code does, instead of a simple code blob.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one argument in predict, namely "type='response'" as we use logs. Then it works!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for including the link to the data. This makes it clear that you have observations that cover a variable number of days. I'm going to assume that your 52 week data are 52 normal, 7 day weeks.

One approach might be to convert the external variable data to a daily rate. For example, if you have 18 cases in 9 days, the daily rate is 2 for each of those 9 days.  Once you have these 365 daily rates, change those days back into the appropriate 52 weeks to match your other variable.

You could incorporate any expected lag in there, if you find out later than this helps.

Of course, any time you have to do something like this, you make it harder to find the connection between the variables. But you don't seem to have a choice.

Comment: Exactly, and to add, it's going to be tricky, because if you use a regression on these daily rates, some measurements should be taken more seriously than others. A small effect that can be ignored, but if you want to get it right, you should take that into account.

Comment: That's what I thought, it seems that next to the interpolation it is only another valid solution. Thank you for your responses!